# Is it possible to have an event automatically created in a SP calendar from a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have managed to create the list (contains title, start date, stop date, location, participants and remarks) that my boss wants (as we use it for the purpose of a tracker) but it also has to be put into a calendar for the rest of my unit to access.  Having said that, we do not have the ability to use Power Automate.  We have access to Nintex Workflow instead.  Currently I am having to re-type the information over and over in each app and if someone else goes and makes a change (as everyone has access and is required to ensure all events are posted), I have to go through all of it to make sure that both are the same.

I have read that many articles trying to find the answer and am more confused now than ever (workflows, forms, lists, calendars, Power Automate,  etc).  I am assuming / hoping there is a much easier way for this to be done? As I am not a SP guru and have not been using it very long, have gone down the proverbial rabbit hole and am getting very frustrated.

Any assistance (step by step) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try using the following Power Automate. in SharePoint Power Automate is able to create a variety of rich workflows to suit your needs.

**First, we need to create a flow.**

1.Sign in to [Power Automate](https://make.powerautomate.com/) with your SharePoint account.

2.Click Create->Select Automated cloud flow.

[image]

3.Enter Flow name and select "When an item is created".This indicates that this flow job is triggered when you create an item.
[image]

**Second step:create the specifics of the flow.**

1.Choose your list.
[image]

2.Next Step is Create Event: Fill the event with some values, where you can get the column values of the item you created and add them as dynamic content to the event.
[image]

3.When you are done, please click save and then create a new item in the list to see if the flow creates the event.
[image]

You see can refer to this [link to learn more about Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/getting-started).

Comment: But author of question said that: "we do not have the ability to use Power Automate".

Comment: I only have access to Nintex Automation Cloud.